# Add email address to php $email_to variable

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form that has a simple check box list. I need the form sent via email to all those based on the boxes that have been checked. Below is the basic logic bit I realize the code is way off.

```
$email_to = 'david@gmail.com,'.'

    if ($_POST['services'] == 'Electrical'){
        echo ",roger@gmail.com";
    }

    if ($_POST['services'] == 'Plumbing'){
        echo ",bill@gmail.com";
    }

    if ($_POST['services'] == 'Painting'){
        echo ",donnie@gmail.com";
    }
.';
```

So the idea is that if the *services* check box includes *Electrical*, then the email variable will include `$email_to = 'david@gmail.com,roger@gmail.com'`

And if the *services* check box includes *Electrical AND Plumbing*, then the email variable will include `$email_to = 'david@gmail.com, roger@gmail.com, bill@gmail.com'`

Any help would be appreciated.

HERE IS THE ACTUAL CODE THAT I TRIED TO IMPLEMENT AFTER RECEIVING YOUR SUGGESTIONS - BUT STILL DOESNT WORK - AND I TRIED ALL THREE SUGGESTIONS?

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_from = $_POST["email"];
$email_to = 'nettemple@gmail.com,{$email_from}';
    if($_POST['services'] == "Ecomtek"){ 
        $email_to .= ",sol@sungazer.com"; 
        }
    if($_POST['services'] == "E-Payroll"){ 
        $email_to .= ",sarah@nettemple.net"; 
        }
    if($_POST['services'] == "Humana"){ 
        $email_to .= ",dmeyers@scad.edu";
        }

$email_subject = "WEB INQUIRY";
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

?>
```

THIS IS THE FORM....

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="form_process2.php">

<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Ecomtek" />&nbsp;Ecomtek<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="E-Payroll" />&nbsp;E-Payroll<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Humana" />&nbsp;Humana<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="John Conti" />&nbsp;John Conti<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Kentucky RX Card" />&nbsp;Kentucky RX Card<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Lifelock" />&nbsp;Lifelock<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Logans" />&nbsp;Logan's<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Norton Healthcare" />&nbsp;Norton Healthcare<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Office Depot" />&nbsp;Office Depot<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="ProWaste" />&nbsp;ProWaste<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Thorntons" />&nbsp;Thorntons<br />


  <label for="firstname">*FirstName</label>
  <input  type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="150" size="50" class="formbox">

  <label for="lastname">*Last Name</label>
  <input  type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="150" size="50" class="formbox">

  <label for="company">*Company</label>
  <input  type="text" name="company" maxlength="150" size="50" class="form box">

  <label for="email">*Email Address</label>
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="180" size="50" class="form box">

</form>
```

Comment: Try this $email_to = 'david@gmail.com';

Comment: You are making echo to mail id not append the second mail id.

Comment: issue with the source of $_POST['services'] and how it can 'includes Electrical AND Plumbing,' is it a text input\check boxes ?

Answer (score 5):

$_POST['services'] is an array so:

```
$email_to = 'david@gmail.com';

    if (in_array('Electrical',$_POST['services'])){
        $email_to .= ",roger@gmail.com";
    }

    if (in_array('Plumbing',$_POST['services'])){
        $email_to .= ",bill@gmail.com";
    }

    if (in_array('Painting',$_POST['services'])){
        $email_to .= ",donnie@gmail.com";
    }
```

`.=` appends the 2nd address to the first

Comment: Ive tried all suggestions and none work. So I posted the actual code and emails at the bottom for clear clarification...

Comment: @NetTemple not clear to me what `$_POST['services'] `  is id you addd `var_dump($_POST)` and show us the output that would help

Comment: I added the form above - does this help?

Comment: updated. i would probably do it another way now that i know what your dong, but this will still work.

Comment: I am getting red error indicators at the start of each "if" line... ? This may be an indicator of why it isn't working?

Comment: @NetTemple fixed. please learn how to accept answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array for this.

```
$emails = array();

if($_POST['services'] == 'Plumbing') {
    $emails[] = 'user@gmail.com';
}

if($_POST['services'] == 'Painting') {
    $emails[] = 'user@gmail.com';
}
```

When going to send the email, I would just iterate the array.

```
foreach( $emails as $email )
    mail($email, 'Subject', ....);
```

Comment: you had better explian how to use the $emails array - ie implode()

Comment: I could, but I prefer to iterate over the array. Not sure of performance issues, but with a couple emails, no biggie. Implementation added.

Comment: what ever floats your boat.

Answer (score 1):

Added `isset($_POST['services'])` to validate variable before use, and for appending the string you can use `.=`

```
$email_to = 'david@gmail.com';
if(isset($_POST['services']){
    if ($_POST['services'] == 'Electrical'){
        $email_to .= ",roger@gmail.com";
    }
    if($_POST['services'] == 'Plumbing'{
        $email_to .= ",bill@gmail.com";
    }
    if($_POST['services'] == 'Painting'){
        $email_to .= ",donnie@gmail.com";
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using (isset($_POST['services']) three times you can use once and after you can check value of variable

Answer (score 1):

```
$email_to = 'david@gmail.com';

    if (in_array('Electrical',$_POST['services'])){
        $email_to .= ",roger@gmail.com";
    }

    if (in_array('Plumbing',$_POST['services'])){
        $email_to .= ",bill@gmail.com";
    }

    if (in_array('Painting',$_POST['services'])){
        $email_to .= ",donnie@gmail.com";
    }
```